# Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length)

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I try to  fetch data from database (MySQL) and have this error.
I face error and couldn't solve it
the code is for notes app with flutter, MySQL , php

But I got an exception, where I know where the exception and what it means, but I do not have any clue how I could solve the problem

This is the code where the error is thrown:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_php_mysql/constant/linkapi.dart';
import 'package:flutter_php_mysql/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_php_mysql/models/cardnote.dart';

import '../models/crud.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final crud = Crud();

  getNotes() async {
    var response = await crud.postRequest(linkViewNote, {
      "userid": sharedPref.getString("id"),
    });
    return response;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                sharedPref.clear();
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("login");
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))
        ],
        title: const Text('Homepage'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getNotes(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot.data["status"] == "failed") {
                    return const Text("no notes found");
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data["info"].length,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CardNote(
                          notetitle:
                              "${snapshot.data["info"][index]["notes_title"]}",
                          notecontent:
                              "${snapshot.data["info"][index]["notes_content"]}",
                          ontap: () {});
                    },
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Only place I see `length` in your code is `itemCount: snapshot.data["info"].length`, so if that is the actual line your error message is referring to, then `snapshot.data["info"]` appears to be null.